# Windows 10 one-hand Shift-mouse drag?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

I am one-handed. In Windows-10 Often I need to perform Shift-mouse-drag or Ctrl-mouse-drag (click) When it comes to capital letters, I can stretch my fingers over the keyboard, but not with a precise mouse drag (click) . I know  the "sticky keys" feature was designed for keyboard combinations", but it does not seem to work for mouse actions, at least not in Word 2016 for Ctrl-click (multiple selection) Is there any similar software solution for mouse actions, such as using the on-screen keyboard?  Or, using  some AHK (or other ) script

Comment: Many of these shortcuts do have a keyboard alternative, such as using shift + arrow keys, or after making a selection, copy/cut, move around, paste. In that case sticky keys will work. Not sure of any alternatives, but that doesn't mean there aren't any. One thing I can think of that would work... if you have a mouse with programmable keys, you could bind one button to shift. Not sure if every mouse with programmable keys also offer using the shift or control key though, so I would at least look for a mouse that does macros.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a third-party app such as [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) to reprogram mouse buttons. That app can be customized with different "layers" for different software. With a [multi-button mouse](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=multibutton%20mouse) such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BN77X6HW) for <US$10, use one of the extra buttons (or the wheel tilt switch on mice like the [Logitech M510](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003NR57BY)) for <kbd>Shift</kbd> and another for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. You might also use one for <kbd>Alt</kbd>, which can be used to drag a *rectangular* region.